# How to hide the name of the last person edited the line?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, gitlens

[image]

I want to hide the details next to the code.

I tried to hide it from the settings, but I couldn't find the option that enables me to hide it.

Comment: This is due to git lens extension in your visual studio code. You can disable it by going into extensions and search for GitLens and then you can disable or uninstall it.

Comment: in such a case find the extension responsible for the stuff, by disabling all or some, and then search its settings and switch it off

Answer (score 2):

Most probably these details are added by Gitlens extension. This specific feature is called *Current Line Blame* and can be disabled by tweaking Gitlens settings. All you need to do is simply go to Preferences and Search for **gitlens current line**. Under Gitlens settings you'll find the **Gitlens > Current Line:Enabled** option. simply uncheck the checkbox for this option and it'll disable the inline commit details.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type: 'Gitlens: Open Settings'
3. Look for '*Annotation format*'
4. Remove `${author, }`

```
${author, }${agoOrDate}${' via 'pullRequest}${ • message|50?}

${agoOrDate}${' via 'pullRequest}${ • message|50?}
```

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]